# PyQT5: wait for signal before continuing the function

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals

using PyQt5 as interface for my program, I wrote a function that is activated by clicking a button, and that function activates (among other things) another function that activates a thread that works on something else while the first function does its job.
My problem is, that the function finishes much faster than the thread, and **I want the program to wait for the thread to end** before moving on, preferably with a timeout option.
I know there are signals in PyQT5, and I know how to trigger events based on a signal given, however, how would I make the program wait for a signal to come?

Thank you very much for the help :)

example code of what I want:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__():
        self.first_function()
        ....
        ....

    def first_function(self):
        ....
        ....
        self.second_function()
        wait_for_signal(timeout=30)

    def second_function(self):
        ....
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_func)
        t.start()
        ....
        ....

    def thread_func(self):
        ....
        ....
        signal.emit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do you need but here is an example of a function that in the start block signals and in the end activate them

```
def show_acte_general(self):
        
        self.comboBox_2.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox_2.clear()
        self.comboBox_4.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox_4.clear()
        
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", password="password", host="localhost", database="database")
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cur.execute('''SELECT items FROM read ORDER BY items ASC;''')
        data = self.cur.fetchall()

        for actes in data :
            self.comboBox_2.addItem(actes[0])
            self.comboBox_2.blockSignals(False)
            
            self.comboBox_4.addItem(actes[0])
            self.comboBox_4.blockSignals(False)
```